# Writing A Subquery with Left and Where

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, subquery

I am trying to make a new column which will take the first letter from the column and then filter the ones that have letter A

ChatGPT totally give me another way but I just want to understand what is wrong with my logic

```
Select Code,  
FROM WIR  
Where Code = 'A'  
(Select Subject,  
Zone_Location,  
Left (Final_Status,1) As Code  
from `poised-shift-415007.WIR.WIR_CEC` As WIR)'''
```

I thought that what between brackets will run first then from the result it will select new column (code) from the table that I just named WIR then put a condition just to show what has letter A. I am sure I am missing some fundamentals here but my experience just from google certificate I am a construction management professional.

What I am trying to understand how can I run a query on the new result after running a previous query

Chatgpt gave me the code that I need but not in a way that I want where I can run more queries on results from previous queries

```
  SELECT 
    YourColumn,   
    LEFT(YourColumn, 1) AS FirstLetter  
FROM   
    YourTable  
WHERE   
    LEFT(YourColumn, 1) = 'A';
```

Comment: Hi - what you’ve written is not valid SQL and has numerous errors in it. I’m going to assume that you’re new to writing SQL, in which case I’d start by taking one of the many online SQL courses - and leave ChatGPT alone

Comment: Yes I can do just basic SQL (I am 70% of the google analytics certificates) but I could not find a comprehensive Subquery course, if you recommend one I will appreciate it, the one who explained it in the course was just reading the code without explaining why and how things are happening. WHy should I leave Chatgpt? when I am stuck with writing a code it answers me!!!

Comment: please give more info about this question. like data structure, schema or maybe chatgpt  answers.

Comment: Hi - without wishing to be too harsh, the fact that none of the SQL statement you provided is correct (ignoring anything to do with sub-queries) suggests you need to improve your basic SQL skills. ChatGPT doesn't explain it's answers - which is exactly what you are complaining about with your course - so you are unlikely to learn much by using it, which is why I suggested you leave it alone (at least until you have more experience)

Comment: You are not harsh but you are not correct this will run fine Select Subject, Zone_Location, Left (Final_Status,1) As Code from poised-shift-415007.WIR.WIR_CEC As WIR, I just wanted to add two orders at the same time based on this one..I am running basic queries, I think chatgpt will help me more..thank you.

Comment: Yes - the SQL in your comment will probably run. But as that SQL is nothing like the SQL in your question I'm not sure of it's relevance? Anyway, as this is turning into a discussion I think I will probably leave it here.

Comment: Its what was between brackets (the first query that I  was trying to run) yes you are right brother lets leave it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as ChatGPT isn't allowed to be used in the questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned keep in mind that SO is not a place to debug or fix ChatGPT answers